# Organizing rest full web service output

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey

I'm writing resfull web service vai Jersey. Returning data in json. 
Web service has 2 method, first returns User object and Second ArrayList of User Object;
This is my User Class

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String surName;
    private String address;
    private int status
    }
```

The problem is that i want to return User with only id, firtName and surName in the first method, output example: `{"id":"1","firstName":"William","surName":"Dodgson"}`
and UserList with id, address in the second method, 
output example:
`[{"id":"1","address":"some address"}, {"id":"2","address":"some address"}]`

How should i manage this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know jersey. But you can divide that class with inheritance.
Firt create a base user class :

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String surName;
}
```

And extended class

```
public class UserMoreInfo extends User {

    private String address;
    private int status
    }
```

Finally in each method you can return distinct object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case my second method will return such Json string: 
[{"id":"1", "firstName":"","surName":"" ,"address":"some address"}, {"id":"2", "firstName":"","surName":"", "address":"some address"}]

I don't want to be firstname and surname in second method's output.

Comment: Why you not consider a Has-A relotion and write two separate class. You can make UserMoreInfo an attribute of User class. Of course you have to duplicate id flied.